# Name of module to be imported to run this Powershell Command

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell, whitelist

I am trying to whitelist some IP addresses to my Azure storage account by using below powershell command

```
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $storageAccountName -IPRule $rule
```

Now this $rule object is an Array of type `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSIpRule`. Link for reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/add-azstorageaccountnetworkrule?view=azps-8.3.0#-iprule)

So I am trying to create these objects using the below command

```
 New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSIpRule
```

I am getting below error while trying to create this object

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSIpRule]:
Verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

I tried googling to import the module that has this assembly, but couldn't find any. What is the module to be imported or is there any other way to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#Load Assembly
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.2

```
using asssembly [path]
using assembly "C:\Users\administrator\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\Az.Storage\4.9.0\Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Storage.Management.dll"
```

After that you can create the object

```
$ipRule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSIpRule
```

which gives you an object with the properties Action and IpAddressOrRange.

The import-module way (module must be stored in a location known by system variable PsModulePath, otherwise you have to specify the path):

```
Import-Module az.storage
$ipRule = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSIpRule
```

To identify which module to load for a specific cmdlet:

```
#Ask get command about the cmdlet
get-command [cmdlet]
get-command Add-AzStorageaccountnetworkrule
#Source tells you where it is coming from
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule                    4.9.0      Az.Storage
```

Comment: I want to run this in agents of devops pipeline. Can we do something like Import-Module <module_Name> -Force?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. How to figure out which Az Module to import for a specific command?